# Parameter in state setup not found

Tags: scala, akka

I am uncountering an error I would really like to solve if possible, not simply finding a way around.

Here is my code:

```
import akka.actor._
import concurrent.duration._

sealed trait Message
case class ReturnInfluenceMessage(source: ActorRef) extends Message
case class SetInfluences(source: ActorRef) extends Message
case class Start(period:Int) extends Message
case object GetInfluence extends Message
case object Stop extends Message
case object TickMessage extends Message

class Listener extends Actor {
    def receive = {
        case _ =>
            println("Listener: received something\n")
    }
}

class Entity extends Actor {
    val router = context.actorOf(Props[Router], name = "Router")

    def receive = {
        case rim @ ReturnInfluenceMessage(source) =>
            source ! rim

        case msg =>
            shadow ! msg
    }
}

class Router extends Actor {
    val pulser = context.actorOf(Props[Pulser], name = "Pulser")
    //more children

    def receive = {
        case rim @ ReturnInfluenceMessage(source) =>
            context.parent ! rim

        case msg =>
            context.children foreach (_.forward(msg))
    }
}

class Pulser extends Actor {
    val clock = context.actorOf(Props[Clock], name = "Clock")

    def receive = {
        case TickMessage =>
            println ("Emission_Unit: received Tickmessage!\n")

        case _  => 
            println ("Emission_Unit: received something\n")
    }
}

class Clock extends Actor { 
    def receive = ready

    def ready:Receive = {
        case Start(period) => {
            println ("Heartbeat: Start")
            context.become(running(period) orElse ready)
            context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(period milliseconds, self, TickMessage)
        }
    }

    def running(period:Int):Receive = {
        case TickMessage => {
            context.parent ! TickMessage
            context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(period milliseconds, self, TickMessage)
        }

        case Stop =>
            println("Clock: stopping")
            context.unbecome()
    }
}

object Main extends App {
    val system = akka.actor.ActorSystem("mySystem")
    val abel = system.actorOf(Props[Listener], name = "Listener")
    val cain = system.actorOf(Props[Entity], name = "Entity")

    import system.dispatcher
    system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(...)
    //do something irrelevant
}
```

This does not compile. It seems the compiler does not recognize the `period` variable on the line:

```
context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(period milliseconds, self, TickMessage)
```

Here is the error:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/yuggoth/witchdoctor/fff/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /home/yuggoth/witchdoctor/fff/src/main/scala/prjt11.scala:64: Cannot find an implicit ExecutionContext. You might pass
[error] an (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) parameter to your method
[error] or import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global.
[error]             context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(period milliseconds, self, TickMessage)
[error]                                                  ^
[error] /home/yuggoth/witchdoctor/fff/src/main/scala/prjt11.scala:71: Cannot find an implicit ExecutionContext. You might pass
[error] an (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) parameter to your method
[error] or import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global.
[error]             context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(period milliseconds, self, TickMessage)
[error]                                                  ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed Sep 2, 2014 4:46:52 PM
```

The thing I am trying to do here is having my `Clock` send `TickMessage` to its `parent Pulser`. I try to do so using state setup I just learned about and no state variable.

Comment: It says it can't find `Execution context`. Add `import context._` before scheduler.

Comment: I did as you said. Adding `import context._` leads to `reference to self ambiguous; it is both defined in trait Actor and imported subsequently by import._`. While I remove `context.` on the next line the compiler tells it adds: `not found: value period`...

Comment: add `.` after `period`. Also, where do you have `import._` ? It's not a good thing to import all at once, but rather make it more explicit.

Comment: I added `.` right after `period` in various combinations not knowing what it means, but the error stays the same. And the `import._` was a miss type, I did as you suggested.

Comment: It should be enough to do `period.miliseconds` it's matter of implicit conversion. But if doesn't help I don't know. You still getting same error message?

Comment: Yes, I still got the same error...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60643/discussion-between-goral-and-wipman).

Answer (score 8):

try with:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The compiler tells you the method `context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce` need an implicit argument `(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)`.

So you need to provide an `ExecutionContext` or to import a scope that will make an `implicit ExecutionContext` visible.

A quick look to the [akka doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/scheduler.html) tells you to use :

`import system.dispatcher`

What they doesn't tell you is to define `system` before as it's not a package but an object:

```
val system = akka.actor.ActorSystem("system")
```

Comment: Yes, but the compiler does not recognize the `system` from the `import system.dispatch`. I got this: `not found: value system`. When I add `context`, I get: `stable identifier required, but Heartbeat.this.context.system found` pointing at the `system` in `import context.system.dispatcher`.